# Include spring context file in gradle distZip package

Tags: gradle

I have a spring context file and a property file located in my project root.

When running `gradle distZip` i get all the sources included as well as the libraries, but how do I also include the two files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the simplest working build files that solves the problem. You can easily make use of `contents` specification in your build. More information about [`CopySpec`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html).

### Using [distribution plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html)

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from "$projectDir" 
            into 'doc'
            include 'README'
        }
    }
}
```

### Using [application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'Main'

applicationDistribution.from("$projectDir") {
     into 'doc'
     include 'README'
}
```

Comment: Hm. Seams like the application plugin (`apply plugin:'application'`) is in conflict with the `distribution` plugin. Any idea how to do this from the application plugin?

Comment: @Theodor Updated answer to include solution for both plugins.